# Video Stabilization for moving camera

Tags: android, opencv, computer-vision, image-stabilization

I need to stabilize the shakes that a moving camera gets, for example, when a person is walking with the camera in his hand.

Till now, I've been able to detect the features of both frames using the FAST feature detector and calculate the displacement of the points.

What should I do next? Other posts suggest calculating the homography matrix and then using it to warp the new frame but will that not distort the linear motion of the camera as well? I just need to remove the shakes.

Answer (score 0):

Try reusing OpenCV's solution: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/videostab/doc/videostab.html

Comment: I have a feeling that porting that to java is not gonna be a piece of cake.

Comment: There should not be anything to port - java is supported natively by OpenCV these days

Comment: I couldn't find any classes containing those functions in OpenCV4Android, so I guess it's still in their TODO list. But hey, what do we have JNI for. I'm gonna try those functions out and get back to you.